# How to proceed after Implementing django tenant schemas

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have successfully implemented django-tenant-schema in my project. It also creates separate schema for each user after they got registered.Suppose if a customer named 'customer1' is successfully logged in, then he will redirect to "customer1.domainname.com".So please suggest me a solution to test if this is working in my local system ahead of being put it in the production environment.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Linux you just have to add that domain name in `/etc/hosts` and access it like it is a real domain name.  Another solution is to make that domain name to point to 127.0.0.1 while you don't push the changes to production.  I'd go with the first idea though.

Comment: Which apps should be add in this Tenant_apps?(I already added one - django.contrib.contenttypes).

Comment: Is it possible to add **django.contrib.auth** here in TENANT_APPS?

Comment: @VijeshVenugopal, you can add django.contrib.auth to TENANT_APPS. Then each customer will have it's own user table. You need to determine which tables should exist once per server and which once per customer.

Comment: @user640916 I have added like you said above and if i choose "example.com", i can be able to login. But in case of sub domain "test.example.com", i can't.

Comment: @VijeshVenugopal: when you try to login on test.example.com you will only be able to do so with an account which exist in the 'test' tenant schema. Check the docs how to use tenant_command and create a superuser for your test tenant. Then try again.